# Unix/Windows dualboot OS-dependent file

Tags: dual-boot, symlink

I'm currently in a dualboot setup, where I work in both Windows and Debian. I've set up my Android development environment to share as many files as possible to save drive space, including my workspace. This works fine, though I run into one problem.

In Android-projects there's a local.properties file, containing the path to the SDK. In windows, this is `C:/blabla/Sdk`. In Debian, it's `~/blabla/Sdk`. Every time I start up my project in the other OS Android Studio gives the message

> Couldn't find SDK, will change local.properties to C:/blabla/Sdk|~/blabla/Sdk.

It works fine, it's just a single click and it's solved. My question, however, is would it be possible to make a link that links to one file on Unix, and a different one on Windows? Where in linux I'd get a file named link that links to `~/target`, and in windows the same file links to `C:/target`?